# Matching multiline string at command line: return certain line if pattern matches, otherwise return empty string

Tags: regex, unix, command-line, pcre, pcregrep

The output of a command I have takes on the following form when it is a "success":

```
/ >  -------
ABC123
/ >
```

It's possible for this command to emit something like this, though (a "failure"):

```
/ >  -------
ABC123
 -------
DEF456
 -------
Hello (world!)
 -------
(any old string, really)
/ >
```

Or, this (another "failure"):

```
/ > / >
```

For the first example, I would like to emit:

```
ABC123
```

For the other two examples, I would like to emit the empty string.

I tried this, which worked great for the third example:

```
mycmd | pcregrep -M '(?:/\s>\s{2}-{7}\n)[^\n]*(?!\n.*\n)'
```

But for the first two examples it emitted:

```
/ >  -------
ABC123
```

I'm at a loss for what to do. My regex above was an attempt to match the leading `/ >  -------` but not capture it, then match the next line only if it was not followed by another line ending with a newline. I am fine with using something other than `pcregrep` to solve this problem, but I am not able to express this with `awk` or `sed`. I would use Python, but it is too slow for my needs. Any help?

Comment: So if in between `/ >` and next `/ >` you have one unique line, print it. Otherwise, print nothing?

Comment: @fedorqui Yes, unless that'd get tripped up with the `  -------` after the first `/ >`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought the following would work, but I could not get a look-behind expression to work if it contained a newline.

```
mycmd | pcregrep -M '(?<=^/ >  -{7}\n).*\n(?=/ > $)'
```

But the following two stage solution worked for me:

```
mycmd | pcregrep -M '^/ >  -{7}\n.*\n/ > $' | pcregrep -v '^/ >'
```

---

***Update in response to OP's answer***

I like the \K escape :-)

I assume you do ***not*** want to match the following situation

```
/ > -------
/ > perhaps text here
/ >
```

I was able to get negative look ahead to work when it contains \n, even when it is embedded within a positive look ahead.

Here is a simpler regex with `\K` that is closer to what you want. It disallows any content after the `/ >`, but it still allows lines before the `/ >  -------`.

```
mycmd | pcregrep -Mo '^/ >  -{7}\n\K(?!/ >).+(?=\n/ > $(?!\n[\s\S]))'
```

If the captured line should be allowed to start with `/ >`, then it is simpler:

```
mycmd | pcregrep -Mo '^/ >  -{7}\n\K.+(?=\n/ > $(?!\n[\s\S]))'
```

---

***Final update***

Here is a sed one liner that I believe gives the exact result, disallowing any extra lines before or after. However, it does allow capturing a line that begins with `/ >`.

```
mycmd | sed -n '1{/^\/ >  -\{7\}$/{n;/./{h;n;/^\/ > $/{${x;p}}}}}'
```

And here is another sed solution

```
mycmd | sed -n '1{h;n;H;x;N;${/^\/ >  -\{7\}\n..*\n\/ > $/{x;p}}}'
```

Comment: I couldn't get look-behinds *nor* negative look-aheads to work... anyway this works (although the first string has to be `'^/ >  -{7}\n.*\n/ > $'`) since there is a trailing space. Thanks!

Comment: @2rs2ts - I've added a sed solution that I think exactly meets your requirements.

Comment: I wish I could upvote you twice! Thank you, these are all great.

Answer (score 1):

You could also still have used awk:

```
BEGIN {
   first_line = "";
   second_line = "";
   third_line = "";

   ctr = 0;
}
{
   if (ctr == 0 ){
      first_line = $0;
   } else if (ctr == 1) {
      second_line = $0;
   } else if (ctr == 2 ) {
      third_line = $0;
   }
   ctr++;
}
END {
   if( first_line ~ /\/ >  -------/){
      if( third_line ~ /\/ >/){
         print second_line;
      }
   }
}
```

Output:

```
$ echo "/ >  -------\nABC12\n ---\n/ >\n" | awk -f test.awk
$ echo "/ >  -------\nABC12\n/ >\n" | awk -f test.awk
ABC12
$
```

I'm sure an awk expert would cringe, but it was quick and did the job.

Comment: I would love not to use a separate file if I use `awk`. But this did work (my apologies for saying it didn't just a moment ago, I made a typo on my machine.)

Comment: No Problem,  For what its worth, you can put it all on the command line, but I thought that squishing it all on one line might be less clear.

Comment: @2rs2ts, why do you want to not use another file?  If you add `#!/usr/bin/awk -f` as the first line of the file and set it executable, you could write `./my_command | ./test.awk`

Comment: Because I'd rather not deploy a `.tar` if I can just deploy a `.sh`. I may just write this all on one line.

Comment: This falsely allows extra line(s) after the closing `/ > `.

Answer (score 1):

I actually achieved success (after much gnashing of my teeth) with the following `pcregrep` command:

```
pcregrep -Mo '^/ > {2}-{7}[\n\r]\K[^\n\r]+(?=[\n\r]/ > $)'
```

Without the `-o` flag it included the first line (despite using `\K`). `-o` makes `pcregrep` emit only the lines which matched the pattern. As it turns out, negative look-aheads don't seem to work with multiline mode when trying to match newlines. Also, in multiline mode, `\s` will match newlines, so I stopped using it.

I do want to note that neither this solution nor dbenham's solution is exactly what I wanted. I was hoping to check that there weren't any *other* lines, besides the last line (i.e. not containing another newline), after the second line. These solutions assume a little more about how the output ends, but that will have to do.

Comment: +1, Nice! I believe you are missing a caret (line begin anchor) at the start of your regex. See my updated answer for a simpler version that I think is also tighter.

Comment: @dbenham Yep, you're absolutely right. (I didn't copy-paste, I actually re-typed it.)